# SQL Server - Table data refresh from different server and different schema

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Requirement : We used to get min 10 to 50 table names (from different schema's and servers(using linked server ) as refresh requests from Prod to Test or Dev environment on regular basis.

Ex: We have 3 schema's called dbo,Schema1 and Schema 2 in prod where as in other environments we have different schema names such as schemaC and SchmaD etc.

For this I am using the below script to get the table names in single quotations.

Step 1 :

Declare @String Varchar(8000) = 'schemaname.table1,schemaname.table2,schemname.table1s45k'

Set @String = '''' + Replace(@String, ',', ''',''') + ''''

Select @String

Step 2 : I will backup the existing tables data in our bkpdata base table.

Step 3 : I will truncate the backedup tables

Step 4: I will move the data from Production to dev / test environment with help of linked server ex: in dev box

Insert into databasename.schemaname.tablename select * from linkedservername.schemaname.tablename

It would be great if we can get dynamic SQL code with parameters facility as Tablenames , databasename,linkedservername and schema name facility.

Any other options also highly appreciated.

adding additional details :

Declare @String Varchar(8000) = 'schema1.rnd,schema2.test'

Set @String = '''' + Replace(@String, ',', ''',''') + ''''

declare @Strings table (names varchar(max))
insert into @strings
select @String

select 'Truncate Table '+''+ name from sys.tables where name in (select name from @strings )

It will display the results as Truncate table Tablename . So I don't want to execute the results and it has to execute the output itself .I guess dynamic SQL Will help.

Comment: Could you please explain in little brief what is exact requirement?

Comment: Sure Poonam. Thanks for Reply. We need to move schema 1. table 1 production data to schema c.table 1 in development environment. If table count is less then we can use import export or insert into select but we have to do several tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
--@String contains location where to(db.schema.tablenm) copy and where from(servevr.dbb.schema.tablenm)
--At the end of each copy and copy from need to provide , as delimeter
--copy to and copy from is seprated by |

Declare @String Varchar(8000) = 
'db.schema.tablenm|servevr.dbb.schema.tablenm,
db1.schema1.tablenm1|servevr1.db1.schema1.tablenm1,
db2.schema2.tablenm2|servevr2.db2.schema2.tablenm2,
'
Declare @str Varchar(8000)
Declare @execStr Varchar(8000)
Declare @delimeterocc int
Declare @delimeterSer int
declare @start int

set @start=0
Set @delimeterocc=charindex(',',@String)
While(@delimeterocc>0)
begin
    set @str=SUBSTRING(@String,@start,len(@string)-(len(@String)-@delimeterocc)-@start)
    Set @delimeterSer=charindex('|',@str)
    print 'Insert Into ' + SUBSTRING(@str,1,@delimeterSer-1)  + ' Select * From '+ SUBSTRING(@str,@delimeterSer+1,len(@str)-@delimeterSer)
    Set @start=@delimeterocc+1
    Set @delimeterocc=charindex(',',@String,@start) 
end
```